# Finding polynomial sequence for given values of x

Tags: algorithm, polynomial-math

Finding the sequence x satisfying

```
    x * <1,1,-1> = <1,0,-1,2,-1>
```

The polynomial corresponds to given sequences for x.

Comment: Could you elaborate that?

Comment: @Mathejunior I have given this sequence and I want to calculate what polynomials correspond to given sequence of x

Comment: do you mean something like f(x) * (1 + x - x^2) = 1 - x^2 + 2x^3 -  x^4 where you want to find f(x)? In that case, it's easy to see why f(x) = [a,b,c]. Then you multiply and match coefficients.

Comment: @Mathejunior yes a polynomial which correspond to given sequence of x (given)

Comment: Well, if `f(x) * (1 + x - x^2) = 1 - x^2 + 2x^3 - x^4`, then `f(x) = (1 - x^2 + 2x^3 - x^4) / (1 + x - x^2)` and this is a simple polynomial division, which is a well known algorithm.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a math problem, not a programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'll use your notation. Since [1,0,-1,2,-1] is a polynomial of degree 4, we can have x as a polynomial of degree 2, assuming that a solution exists.

Denote x := [a,b,c] where a,b,c are the polynomial coefficients.

x * [1,1,-1] = [a,b,c] * [1,1,-1] = [a,a+b,-a+b+c,-b+c,-c]

Equate this with [1,0,-1,2,-1] to get a = 1, a + b = 0 which means b = -1 and -c = -1 which gives c = 1. Note that the system is not inconsistent, which is straight-forward upon calculation.